# what is two species Bose Hubbard Model? what chage it takes on Fock basis representation?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, computational-physics, bose-einstein-condensate

The Hamiltonian will look like
\begin{equation}
\ H= -t^a\sum_{<i,j>}^{}(a_i^\dagger a_i + h.c.)-t^b\sum_{<i,j>}^{}(b_i^\dagger b_i + h.c.)+U^a/2\sum_{i}^{}n_i^a(n_i^a-1)+U^b/2\sum_{i}^{}n_i^b(n_i^b-1)+U^{ab}\sum_{i}^{}n_i^an_i^b \dots(1)
\end{equation}

How it will operated in Number State representation? or more clearly how number will look?
for example consider 3 sites and 2 bosons [1,0,1] this will be a one state if ***H*** have only ***a*** or ***b*** terms. Since ***H*** contains ***a*** and ***b*** so how corresponding state will represented for ***H***?
thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you call "one state". With only one species, the Fock state basis is of the form

$|n_1,n_2,n_3\rangle$

which gives the number of particle on the sites $1$, $2$, $3$. This is one state of the system (even though it is not a eigenstate).

In the case with two species, one can trivially generalize the notation, with a basis

$|n^a_1,n^b_1,n^a_2,n^b_2,n^a_3,n^b_3\rangle$.

So your notation $[1,0,1]$ is ambiguous if you don't explain what the number are, even in with one species (it could be $[n_2,n_1,n_3]$, etc.). Once you have chosen a convention, there is no ambiguity left.